# Wrong BoundingBox dimension extraction pythonocc

Tags: python, 3d, stp, pythonocc

I am trying to extract box dimensions from the STP file and it's worked for a some of the samples, but unfortunately, I got the wrong extraction for the other samples for example below zipped STP file

https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-demos/files/5272793/Test.zip

I got this results value for "x": 6.802000200000001
but the right value is 6.24, and so on for y and z values.

and here is my code

```
from future import print_function

from OCC.Extend.DataExchange import read_step_file
from OCC.Core.IFSelect import IFSelect_RetDone
from OCC.Core.Bnd import Bnd_Box
from OCC.Core.BRepBndLib import brepbndlib_Add
from OCC.Core.BRepMesh import BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh
from OCC.Core.STEPControl import STEPControl_Reader

shapes = read_step_file('path/to/stpfile')

def read_stp_file(file_path):
step_reader = STEPControl_Reader()
status = step_reader.ReadFile(file_path)
if status == IFSelect_RetDone:
fails_only = False
step_reader.TransferRoots()
shape = step_reader.Shape(1)
return shape
else:
print("Error: can't read file.")

bbox = Bnd_Box()

use_mesh = True
mesh = BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh()
mesh.SetParallelDefault(True)
mesh.SetShape(shapes)
mesh.Perform()
assert mesh.IsDone()
brepbndlib_Add(shapes, bbox, use_mesh)
xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax = bbox.Get()
print('x value : >>>> ', xmax - xmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem.

I think the reason is, as the [documentation of Get](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_bnd___box.html#a1e2edaad437806efe0a73a8a57946686) also states, that some kind of gap is included.

You can also see it in the [code here](https://git.dev.opencascade.org/gitweb/?p=occt.git;a=blob;f=src/Bnd/Bnd_Box.cxx;h=3f9ea999ffbd32bc8d797e002328b740c5a35a99;hb=04f0f1b046fd90b263cb9c1071f468ff7888e94c#l166).

It seems the gap is being added by Enlarge in [this function](https://git.dev.opencascade.org/gitweb/?p=occt.git;a=blob;f=src/BRepBndLib/BRepBndLib.cxx;h=6aa8c2dd49845827fd3030ee4f6178010b14e307;hb=0a419c51eda746c42eefb06f94a3e1384acb9a1c#l77).

As the gap is simply added around the bounding box, you can just get it via `GetGap()` and remove it again from all sides. Or you use `SetGap` to set it to 0.

I personally have no idea why this gap is being added, but the docs of `BRepBndLib::Add` even say so: `The resulting bounding box may be somewhat larger than the object.`